# Node.js Asynchronous Concurrent PHP Executions

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, asynchronous, concurrency

I am creating a hybrid node.js and php system. I am currently looking at a concurrency problem that when node.js executes php scripts there seems to be an issue of collision but I am not sure if that's the case. Consider my source code:

node.js code: (async-test.js)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    async = require('async');

cmd = "php echo.php";
// log("cmd: "+cmd);


Util = {
  execute : function(obj, callback){
    exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      obj.out = stdout;
      callback(obj);
    });
  },
  uniqid : function() {
    function s4() {
      return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
    }

    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
      s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
  }
};

/**
 * scenario 1: execute immediately in foreach loop
 */
function scenario_1(num_executions) {
  for (var i = 0; i < num_executions; i++) {
    obj = {
      id : Util.uniqid()
    }

    console.time("php echo.php: "+obj.id);
    Util.execute(obj, function(obj){
      console.timeEnd("php echo.php: "+obj.id);
    });
  } 
}

/**
 * scenario 2: execute using async module
 */
function scenario_2(num_executions) {
  tasks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < num_executions; i++) {
    task = function(){
      obj = {
        id : Util.uniqid()
      }

      console.time("php echo.php: "+obj.id);
      Util.execute(obj, function(obj){
        console.timeEnd("php echo.php: "+obj.id);
      });
    }

    tasks.push(task);
  }

  async.parallel(tasks); 
}
```

php code: (echo.php)

```
<?php 
echo "something done!";
?>
```

As you can see, my objective is that node.js will run multiple php scripts concurrently. The issue however is when multiple or more than 1 php script is executed, the duration of the execution of the php scripts stack up. Here are the scenarios:

```
scenario_1(5):
php echo.php: 4f6140f2-cb89-4c54-d75a-0814370661d5: 645ms
php echo.php: aac0a659-1ef5-29c6-37e8-bc6c59bfeeea: 657ms
php echo.php: c34a4368-82b9-10ad-9add-59b321f03d91: 656ms
php echo.php: 17bc6134-f57c-227f-720d-89b21867af0e: 868ms
php echo.php: 134065e2-ea4f-e9a9-0166-d1999d74cb1d: 944ms

scenario_1(10):
php echo.php: c8c55c6e-df10-9c66-1b7d-8e866b0f5a0c: 1242ms
php echo.php: 9b75d915-2615-0092-bff1-ca1bb09cc3c5: 1254ms
php echo.php: 0c5cc8d9-219d-3e4b-ac7f-f0f533035a7a: 1261ms
php echo.php: fed597e5-c5fa-a064-f1b7-6ad7a2f5797d: 1266ms
php echo.php: 8e09ebb0-55f0-15fc-c1b2-444997c352cc: 1282ms
php echo.php: ae0eb4e0-0031-d056-6a0a-4d476b69bf5d: 1265ms
php echo.php: 23e356a9-7f0d-c0f3-f659-ca13255b0e12: 1326ms
php echo.php: 195313ee-963d-5dac-d4af-55c089b4b749: 1448ms
php echo.php: e5557819-9a49-b58c-ba4f-c87b878f0ba5: 1816ms
php echo.php: 04034c39-d120-8a67-e634-6bb16859409e: 1827ms

scenario_2(1):
php echo.php: faf1a9f7-900d-f757-7cd8-52d3a61328b0: 560ms

scenario_2(5):
php echo.php: 013743b0-47e0-b1d8-2c72-becd7d880832: 636ms
php echo.php: b1e6f53f-5a92-a459-db88-b3c2e36d920d: 646ms
php echo.php: b78550d3-bee8-38c8-3730-ba45706545d4: 710ms
php echo.php: 0a1a0c25-5114-07f8-54d3-ee43b71f9a7e: 900ms
php echo.php: a65bde54-103d-446e-3435-46cb2a30e304: 912ms

scenario_2(10):
php echo.php: c6af334b-af87-3a14-2fc4-1a64a584fe13: 1222ms
php echo.php: 4495203d-eddd-37d3-e29c-9a8c04b85c36: 1240ms
php echo.php: a4344b25-5095-337f-aee6-8bab68f8693f: 1257ms
php echo.php: fbbe9e58-f7ff-1cc9-ab1a-a4b9ebe6f97a: 1304ms
php echo.php: 981eb8a4-e705-062a-30ab-0960f3937c30: 1317ms
php echo.php: 0e032ddf-6844-2a90-5781-3dd66392e5e0: 1355ms
php echo.php: 62180284-9987-8f19-8ae6-ef5e5538db22: 1375ms
php echo.php: 96895ee1-c750-fdec-da9f-d5759017f0f0: 1386ms
php echo.php: fe86da3f-827c-df64-485c-93ecf0eaf74f: 1424ms
php echo.php: 2edef0ec-580d-0148-c889-5ef77ab062e1: 1557ms

scenario_2(20):
php echo.php: b5c42915-3d6b-8119-5eed-6142f0a22f1f: 782ms
php echo.php: aa493142-bc6b-9f47-7812-6f6ba8840968: 793ms
php echo.php: 73b33e76-6777-4236-b7c7-faccb55273b8: 811ms
php echo.php: 814e2db2-8b20-b8ce-1c69-f8cdfd879b76: 809ms
php echo.php: a41c5696-5cc7-5a69-bdbe-c5233b918301: 2283ms
php echo.php: 2d171035-7898-ebaa-af5b-8836dc4ad543: 2211ms
php echo.php: c76b9d4a-c4cb-2617-77d4-ec1afb6b2aff: 2270ms
php echo.php: 0f117dd5-3d87-e43f-81be-d65974c2e396: 2196ms
php echo.php: 2b0318c4-b86d-bb3a-612c-c457cf37f436: 2299ms
php echo.php: a3b4ca39-e26c-612b-6435-d3ba199321fa: 2309ms
php echo.php: 9eccd022-f2de-b8ee-2572-139b1bf6efb3: 2289ms
php echo.php: 75c0cd8d-881e-6925-b89a-933bf1d9be5e: 2307ms
php echo.php: f082c8cd-08ac-70e0-1888-23015bb021ed: 2413ms
php echo.php: a1ab50c3-d7ac-b0da-5e9b-26728547df51: 2439ms
php echo.php: 83a85b6d-236a-265d-3a6f-fdf065c7a486: 2328ms
php echo.php: a4dc49c1-b4a5-ca18-a1cd-fa0dcd36f9cd: 2464ms
php echo.php: 666778e2-ed20-32d9-6df7-592d3bbe5059: 2414ms
php echo.php: b97cb8fe-086f-46aa-31da-37c6aede69d9: 2388ms
php echo.php: 5ba386cb-352d-a2f2-2328-7a132c51b14b: 2473ms
php echo.php: 888bc9aa-bff5-7f14-846a-a6d847db44e6: 2779ms
```

Here's my question:
Is there a way to optimize the running of php scripts simultaneously? Because when I only run scenario_2(1), you can see that the total execution time of a single script is 560 milliseconds but when I run scenario 2 with 10 or more executions you can see that the execution times exceed a second! I have also used the async module for node.js but its still the same.

Also, consider that the php script being executed is only echoing a simple string but why does it take more than a second to execute more than 10 of these simultaneously in node.js?

Is there a way to have 500+ milliseconds for every php script executed even if I have 10 or more simultaneous executions?

Comment: Careful with this... without limiting php subprocess you might find yourself being unintentionally ddosed.

Comment: Keep in mind that every time you run this task, you're building a new child process environment, invoking the PHP interpreter, parsing the PHP file, running the PHP file, etc...  Even if you have only one line of PHP, most of the time is overhead to get the execution envirionment set up and running.  Once you have more of these processes going than you have cores on your processor, they are going to time slice and slow down.

Comment: So, if one run takes 560ms when nothing else is going on with the CPU, then unless you have 10 or more cores, there is no way you're going to run 10 of them at once and still be 560ms to finish them all.  At this point, it's really just CPU math (assuming the overall task is CPU-bound).

Comment: Note: if there's not a lot of PHP code running, then your tasks might be mostly startup/shutdown overhead.  It might make more sense to just have a couple PHP servers running and just feed them requests.  You would avoid all the overhead of starting, loading, parsing scripts and then exiting PHP processes.

Comment: @MinusFour thank you for the input, i'll keep that in mind! can you please suggest an alternative to this?

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you so much for the info. question though, are there any alternatives to consider instead of running the processes one by one?

Comment: My last comment before this one already suggested an alternative.  Have constantly running PHP servers and just send requests to them.  Save all the process overhead.

Comment: @jfriend00 ahh, feeding requests like curl? or something of the like?

Comment: Analogous to curl requests perhaps, but you can just use either the `http` module or the `request` module (easier) to make the requests directly from your node.js code.  No need to invoke `curl`.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00, I will be posting the answer based from your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just posting @jfriend00 's solution from the comments; I have implemented an http request instead of running php scripts via cli.

here's the updated source code for node.js: (async-test.js)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    async = require('async'),
    http = require('http');

cmd = "php echo.php";
// log("cmd: "+cmd);

Util = {
  execute : function(method, obj, callback){
    if (method == "cli") {
      /**
       * cli implementation
       */
      exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        obj.out = stdout;
        callback(obj);
      });
    }else if(method == "curl"){
      /**
       * curl implementation
       * note: echo.php file is located in the htdocs folder
       *       and running an apache/httpd server
       */
      http.get({
        host : "localhost",
        port : 80,
        path : "/echo.php",
        method : "get"
      }, function(resCurl){
        var data = "";

        resCurl.on('data', function(chunk){
          data += chunk;
        });

        resCurl.on('end', function(){
          obj.out = data;
          // console.log({response : data});
          callback(obj);
        });
      });
    }
  },
  uniqid : function() {
    function s4() {
      return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
    }

    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
      s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
  }
};

/**
 * scenario 1: execute immediately in foreach loop
 */
function scenario_1(method, num_executions) {
  for (var i = 0; i < num_executions; i++) {
    obj = {
      id : Util.uniqid()
    }

    console.time("php echo.php: "+obj.id);
    Util.execute(method, obj, function(obj){
      console.timeEnd("php echo.php: "+obj.id);
    });
  } 
}

/**
 * scenario 2: execute using async module
 */
function scenario_2(method, num_executions) {
  tasks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < num_executions; i++) {
    task = function(){
      obj = {
        id : Util.uniqid()
      }

      console.time("php echo.php: "+obj.id);
      Util.execute(method, obj, function(obj){
        console.timeEnd("php echo.php: "+obj.id);
      });
    }

    tasks.push(task);
  }

  async.parallel(tasks); 
}
```

here are the updated scenarios

```
scenario_1("curl", 10):
php echo.php: 6d01308f-b0ab-8046-bbf6-87380d92aa81: 11ms
php echo.php: 09594593-e44f-76f6-8895-25dfdbaa9a23: 9ms
php echo.php: f1893c6f-f268-a909-f5c8-557a2040281b: 10ms
php echo.php: 29777ae7-97f5-9a58-10cc-0a7e7385ee68: 10ms
php echo.php: 5814ca5f-9b45-fe21-1882-fd8486c9e566: 11ms
php echo.php: 65b48d31-007c-d25f-199a-dfb7cc7a873c: 11ms
php echo.php: b2c69a49-d7c1-ffb6-bc9c-9a6e07d51840: 12ms
php echo.php: cebf2b11-d704-f260-2e0b-ec9d261d8e9a: 13ms
php echo.php: 254963bd-7143-850e-fdbd-fae444617c7b: 13ms
php echo.php: 3e5f35b9-bb7f-fcf7-877e-5cd4a895e55d: 14ms

scenario_2("curl", 10):
php echo.php: 54564c27-f48b-c69d-9e3c-4473ea8f7135: 10ms
php echo.php: 57f07115-c02f-16a7-7b46-ec0480d32ec9: 9ms
php echo.php: 6f0d7611-c3a8-574a-dd28-30d2d78c50c0: 9ms
php echo.php: b17f3d63-b9a7-761c-6cb4-a3e9113abf04: 11ms
php echo.php: 60b90263-6bd2-df6b-b8ca-9979fe4dd998: 11ms
php echo.php: a341284b-f791-9dbb-fad1-ef4422ba075f: 11ms
php echo.php: 6964f00a-52e3-ad7f-1051-b263baecf928: 12ms
php echo.php: d096e0ed-5d1f-2e06-6ff3-31d6379c522a: 12ms
php echo.php: 3e357403-541c-acd1-1b7f-da7c2d463fb2: 13ms
php echo.php: a517273f-7412-b818-d3ec-c8b1c706eaa0: 13ms
```

the http solution solved the problem

by @jfriend00 from the comments:

> Note: if there's not a lot of PHP code running, then your tasks might
>   be mostly startup/shutdown overhead. It might make more sense to just
>   have a couple PHP servers running and just feed them requests. You
>   would avoid all the overhead of starting, loading, parsing scripts and
>   then exiting PHP processes.

Comment: Wow, from 560ms for 1 task to no more than 14ms when running 10 tasks.  That's a gigantor improvement!

Comment: @jfriend00, yes, I didn't expect the outcome would be that great either! thanks for your comments earlier.